# Is there a short form of Python with statement using a list of items

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

In this Python code snippet:

```
import threading

a = [threading.Lock(), threading.Lock(), threading.Lock()]

# with a as [a0, a1, a2]:
with a[0] as a0, a[1] as a1, a[2] as a2:
  print(a0, a1, a2)
```

is there a way to write a line similar to the commented one instead of a long version of `with` statement? My use case is not with locks, but with cameras. Posting a short, working snippet is not feasible, though.